# Foundation 5 social icons in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am looking for a method to used the foundation icons within Rails. I did come across a couple of gems like
https://github.com/zaiste/foundation-icons-sass-rails

Is there any other way to do this, I mean I already have the gem 'foundation-rails' gem installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foundation-rails gem does not include the icons automatically. You need to download the icons and include them in your rails application.

Once you include the icons you can use them like so:

```
<i class="fi-[icon]"></i>
```

The foundation-icons-sass-rails gem helps by downloading and importing the icons for you. But, you can do the same manually.

http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3#customize